# Rep changes not popping up in navbar (FIXED)

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, notifications

None of my Rep changes (positive or negative) are showing up in the achievements drop down in the top nav bar.

I know I gained rep today and my total rep is correct, but I did not receive the notification. Not sure if this should be posted in our meta, or if this is a SE problem.

Comment: Seems network-wide issue (again): [Reputation changes not visible in the achievement box (again)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315892)

Comment: Just saw a +x on my navbar... seems like all the +X's that didn't appear are now showing up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Seems that the rep changes are now reported immediately, as well as the ones that weren't reported are now on, and the total rep matches the one made.

---

Seems that this is [starting to get fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315912/332286). I am now starting to receive notifications from rep changes that weren't reported before.

Still, not getting all of them, nor the number matches the total rep yet, but perhaps in a while it will catch up:

[image]

Comment: as of today, I am got/ am getting all of them